# How to get FB access_token from python console app?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-access-token

I have a console application that should get a list of people who liked my page.
As far as I understood I should run something like

```
QUERY = 'SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=__MY_PAGE_ID__'
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" + QUERY
data = requests.get(url)
```

but iI need to use some access token, and I don't understand what kind of. I have log and pass for user with administrative rights on this PAGE. But thay said that I can't get user token without interacting with web browser. 
So I need to use app? Should I create it before somehow? How can you allow this app to get admin account on the page? 
Thanks

Comment: FQL will be removed in the next week, when API v2.0 gets retired. There is no replacement – you can not get a list of all people who liked your page via API.

Comment: Unfortunatelly It is true.